# sorting a json array programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is th json, this need to be filtered based on the "testType" equal to 'R' also had to sort based on "createdDate"

```
{
  "code": null,
  "message": "Total 1 records found",
  "result": {
    "size": 0,
    "dob": 412977600000,
    "sex": "F",
    "visitMasts": [
      {
        "createdBy": 61,
        "visitId": 1235,
        "ordersList": [
          {
            "testId": 4,
            "ordersDto": {
              "orderId": 50815,
              "testType": "R",
              "createdDate": 1479277029456
            }
          },
          {
            "testId": 4,
            "ordersDto": {
              "orderId": 50807,
              "testType": "R",
               "createdDate": 1479016014784
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The filtering is achieved using this,

```
  vm user = response.data.result;
   if (vm.user.visitMasts[0].ordersList != null && vm.user.visitMasts[0].ordersList.length > 0) {
     radioTestDetails = filterFilter(vm.user.visitMasts[0].ordersList, {
      ordersDto: {
       testType: 'R'
      }
     });
    }
```

How can I sort the value based on this

```
response.data.result in that visitMasts -> orderList[] -> createdDate
```

Comment: Try this `(vm.user.visitMasts[0].ordersList.sort(function(l,r){return l.createdDate - r.createdDate})`

Comment: You can just use angular's orderBy filter in your controller. First inject $filter into your controller and then just do something like: `$filter('orderBy')(radioTestDetails, 'ordersDto. createdDate')` to reverse order, just add a third parameter set to true: `$filter('orderBy')(radioTestDetails, 'ordersDto. createdDate', true)`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko (vm.user.visitMasts[0].ordersList.sort(function(l,r){return l.createdDate - r.createdDate}) - creationDate is inside ordersDto ,

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez : Is there any way it will filter with date & time stamp. currently filtering based on date only.

Comment: Well, just replace `l.createdDate` to `l.ordersDto.createdDate`. Like this `vm.user.visitMasts[0].ordersList.sort(function(l,r){return l.ordersDto.createdDate - r.ordersDto.createdDate}`

Comment: @user630209 not sure what you mean.  I don't see a timestamp field,  just a date created field.